# Component height depending on content length

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

My goal: adjust the height of the element depending on the content content.

As we see in the example below, the height of ScrollArea.Root is h-[225px] and everything works fine if the length of the Array === 50. But if we change the length of the Array === 1, then we will see how the height of the ScrollArea.Root does not change (lots of useless white background).

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nervous-mopsa-vnr7nt

Tell me how in this case you can change the height depending on the length of the Array. That is, yes, I am happy with a height of 225px if the Array has many elements (50 by default), but if the number of elements in the Array is made 1 or 2, then you can see that there is white space left, which I would like to get rid of.

```
    const ScrollAreaDemo = () => (
  <ScrollArea.Root className="w-[200px] h-[225px] rounded overflow-hidden shadow-[0_2px_10px] shadow-blackA4 bg-white">
    <ScrollArea.Viewport className="w-full h-full rounded">
      <div className="py-[15px] px-5">
        <div className="text-violet11 text-[15px] leading-[18px] font-medium">
          Tags
        </div>
        {TAGS.map((tag) => (
          <div
            className="text-mauve12 text-[13px] leading-[18px] mt-2.5 pt-2.5 border-t border-t-mauve6"
            key={tag}
          >
            {tag}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </ScrollArea.Viewport>
  </ScrollArea.Root>
);

export default ScrollAreaDemo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned you like the height at  `h-[225px]` but if you changed it to `h-auto` and set the max height to `max-h-[225px]` and change `overflow-hidden` to `overflow-scroll` it would solve the issue.

```
import React from "react";
import * as ScrollArea from "@radix-ui/react-scroll-area";

const TAGS = Array.from({ length: 50 }).map(
  (_, i, a) => `v1.2.0-beta.${a.length - i}`,
);

const ScrollAreaDemo = () => (
  <ScrollArea.Root className="w-[200px] h-auto max-h-[225px] rounded overflow-scroll shadow-[0_2px_10px] shadow-blackA4 bg-white">
    <ScrollArea.Viewport className="w-full h-full rounded">
      <div className="py-[15px] px-5">
        <div className="text-violet11 text-[15px] leading-[18px] font-medium">
          Tags
        </div>
        {TAGS.map((tag) => (
          <div
            className="text-mauve12 text-[13px] leading-[18px] mt-2.5 pt-2.5 border-t border-t-mauve6"
            key={tag}
          >
            {tag}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </ScrollArea.Viewport>
    <ScrollArea.Scrollbar
      className="flex select-none touch-none p-0.5 bg-blackA3 transition-colors duration-[160ms] ease-out hover:bg-blackA5 data-[orientation=vertical]:w-2.5 data-[orientation=horizontal]:flex-col data-[orientation=horizontal]:h-2.5"
      orientation="vertical"
    >
      <ScrollArea.Thumb className="flex-1 bg-mauve10 rounded-[10px] relative before:content-[''] before:absolute before:top-1/2 before:left-1/2 before:-translate-x-1/2 before:-translate-y-1/2 before:w-full before:h-full before:min-w-[44px] before:min-h-[44px]" />
    </ScrollArea.Scrollbar>
    <ScrollArea.Scrollbar
      className="flex select-none touch-none p-0.5 bg-blackA3 transition-colors duration-[160ms] ease-out hover:bg-blackA5 data-[orientation=vertical]:w-2.5 data-[orientation=horizontal]:flex-col data-[orientation=horizontal]:h-2.5"
      orientation="horizontal"
    >
      <ScrollArea.Thumb className="flex-1 bg-mauve10 rounded-[10px] relative before:content-[''] before:absolute before:top-1/2 before:left-1/2 before:-translate-x-1/2 before:-translate-y-1/2 before:w-full before:h-full before:min-w-[44px] before:min-h-[44px]" />
    </ScrollArea.Scrollbar>
    <ScrollArea.Corner className="bg-blackA5" />
  </ScrollArea.Root>
);

export default ScrollAreaDemo;
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! But in this case, the standard CSS scroll appears horizontally and vertically. Can this be somehow avoided? I would like to keep the scrolling option that the library offers

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the max-h on the viewport rather than on the root element.